# Need Laptop recommendation for outdoors photography

Tags: laptop

I have been tasked on finding a **prebuilt laptop** for a motorbike racing enthusiast.

You see, currently he takes a professional quality photos on his camera and then stores them to a external hard drive from the camera. He would like the ability to store the pictures on this laptop, so **capacity** is a big deal. He wants to be able to view the pictures he has taken. He likes the sound of being able to edit the images using Adobe Photoshop (which he has already purchased) though he says this is **not necessary.**

Finally his price range has a **max range of £600** (Their may be some leeway if the increased expense is worth the additional specs) The reason why the price range is so low is that if he drops the laptop in mud, or leaves his laptop behind accidently, it wont be a massive loss. 
He lives in the UK

Any help appreciated.